# How to render primefaces lineChart only when a button is clicked

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Good day!

I'm new to Primefaces and JSF, and it seeems that the tutorial on showcase is only showing an example of the lineChart on page load, my problem is i don't need to display the chart on page load but on a button click rather. But it seems that the chart doesn't render unless you initialize it via the @PostConstruct annotation same as the example on the showcase website.

Is it possible to load only the graph on a click of a button?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

ChartView use same code on the showcase.the element can't be updated if it doesn't exist so put your code in outputpanel and update it.

```
<p:outputPanel id="toUpdate" >
        <p:panel id="myPanel" rendered="#{chartView.flag}">
                <p:chart  id="chart" type="line" model="#{chartView.lineModel1}" style="height:300px;" />
        </p:panel>
</p:outputPanel>
<p:commandButton value="load chart" update="toUpdate" action="#{chartView.setFlagToTrue()}" />
```

...

```
private boolean flag;

public void setFlagToTrue() {
    this.flag = true;
}

public boolean isFlag() {
    return flag;
}
```